I'm facing a problem on jupyter notebook When I type b in user input box everytime it generates a cell, but I want to input b as a user input
I am facing a prblm on jupyter notebook
When I type b in user input box everytime it generates a cell, but I want to input b as a user input.what to do for fixing the prblm?
I tried various individual alphabet where I found that v,b,y and some other alphabet isn't responding

Just to be sure: you're otherwise able to enter text into the cell, and while you're entering text, the cells get inserted etc.? Those seem like Jupyter Notebook keyboard shortcuts, but it's odd they're getting activated while you're entering text.

It seems like when you type in "b" either by itself or as a part of another input, such as "beta" that a new cell is created. That can be frustrating. I'd like you to check if you have the "Vimium" browser extension installed. Vimium assigns shortcuts like a,b, y,n to keys. So, perhaps if you typed ESC to exit any active cell, and then type the "b" or desired input then if successful, would mean that Vimium was intercepting the keystrokes. It is possible to check the preferences in Vimium and add the rule that b or any desired input should not be a recorded keystroke.
There could be problems related to the Jupyter notebook itself like the kernel which can be restarted This can be done by clicking on the "Kernel" option in the toolbar and clicking "Restart and clear output". This will restart the kernel and you can start typing again.
Make sure you do not have extensions that have conflicting key bindings and review your Jupyter notebook configuration settings. Its generally a good idea also to update Jupyter notebook. One method is to clear the browser cache and cookies.
Using these methods you should get a resolution of the issue. Sounds good?
